# With DesiredCapabilities deprecated, how will I use SetCapability in selenium webdriver C #?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

With DesiredCapabilities deprecated, how will I use SetCapability in selenium webdriver C #?

Can I use it this way?

```
capacidades = new ChromeOptions();
capacidades.AddAdditionalCapability(@"browserName", @"chrome");
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Returns execution error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `DesiredCapabilities`, you should be using a browser-specific “Options” class, just as shown in your example. However, you can only call `AddAdditionalCapability` for capability names that do not already have a type-safe property or method to set the capability value. In the case of the `browserName` capability, there is already a `BrowserName` property to access the value of that capability. The runtime exception you receive should have the name of the property or method to use in place of manually setting the capability with that name, but I believe there is a bug that does not properly format the exception message.

Note, however, that the `BrowserName` property is read-only, because since you’re using `ChromeOptions`, the bindings already know the browser name should be “chrome”.

Comment: Thank you very much, your help was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a simple example to the answer from JimEvans.

Simple Example to disable chrome info bars:

```
private IWebDriver GetChromeDriver()
{
    var outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    //Disable chrome info bar in order to prevent "Chrome is being run by automation software."
    var chromeOption = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOption.AddArguments("disable-infobars");

    return new ChromeDriver(outPutDirectory, chromeOption);
}
```

Comment: Not what I need to know is how I will perform the browser configuration in the cloud capabilities. That does not suit my scenario.